# How can I update multiple rows in a Model using a form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a small app in rails where investors can see their balances. The balances are updated by an admin.

The investors are all in a Model called User - is there any way to set up one form in one view where User.balance can be updated for all Users?

The fields in the view can be populated using a <% User.each do |u| %> loop, I guess, but how can I handle the data in the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible. But depends how you are making your form to capture

Comment: For clarification, is `User.balance` manually entered or based off a formula or other data or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, it's manually entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be convenient to implement this in an index view, by using an Ajax-capable gem such as best_in_place, which would let the values be edited in place without the form being submitted.

Comment: I set up best_in_place, and the UI works well, but the data does not get saved to the controller. This is what I have "<% @users.each do |u| %><!--some extra rows--><%= best_in_place u, :balance %>"

Comment: Have you modified the correct controller to respond to the best-in-place request?

Comment: Yeah, users_controller is set up to handle the request with JSON - I followed the railscast.

Comment: def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
   user.update(user_params)
     respond_with user
      flash[:success] = "Investor data successfully updated!"
 end
Note: the user should have an @ which the site isn't letting me add

Comment: Typically we would respond_with_bip(@user) when responding to a best-in-place JSON request

Comment: It turns out I hadn't permitted the balance attribute in user_params :D